# PHP - problem with Semantic URL Query String

Tags: .htaccess

I try to send query string with Semantic URL.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?link=$1 [NC,L]
```

when i try 'localhost/product' it work and direct me to product.php but when i try to send query string :

localhost/product/Acer-s7

It won't work.

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, that is usually the culprit in situations where you have a partial overlap of the “fake” URL, and actually existing file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe comment. its working now i should disable `MultiViews` by adding this code to my .htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes